# Extention .msg in iis server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis-7

I'm trying to open .msg file but it won't even if i add this

```
      <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".msg" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".msg" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-outlook" />
        </staticContent>
```

i also tryed to add it manually in IIS Server b-t it doesn't work

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What behavior are you getting? Are you getting an error? Please describe it in detail. Why did you tag this as both ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core?

Comment: because i'm using asp.net core .. when i'm trying to download .msg file it's given blank page without nothing .. but when i'm trying to download .jpg file or something else its working fine

Comment: Then why did you tag this question as ASP.NET? My point is that you need to tag your question with only the relevant technologies. Please edit your question's tags appropriately to reflect your context. And if you're just getting a blank page when you try to access the .msg file, what does your browser's network tab tell you in the developer tools? What's the HTTP status code of the response?

Comment: returning this **The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.**

Comment: Are you wanting to view the .msg file in the browser? That would mean that the browser needs to know how to open a .msg file. I don't know that they support that. If you just want to download the file and then view it with Outlook, then have you tried saving the file to your disk and then opening it?

Comment: i junt need to download it but i can't , the file is attached in my server

Comment: How did you download the .msg file? If you download this file through code, can you share part of the code? This may be related to your code.